# Integral of Function of Brownian Motion w.r.t Time (Context: Computing Quadratic Variation)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic

I am looking to compute the quadratic variation of $$S_t = S_0e^{\sigma B_t}$$ where $B_t$ is Brownian Motion. Applying Itô's lemma, I having the following
$$(dS_t)^2 = S_0^2\sigma^2e^{2\sigma B_t}dt$$ Now here is where I am a bit confused... how is this actually computed?

I know that the following can't be solved using traditional calc (given that $B_t$ is not differentiable) $$S_0^2\sigma^2\int_0^Te^{2\sigma B_t}dt$$

Do I apply Ito's lemma again, assuming something like $$f_{xx}(t,x) = e^{2\sigma x}$$ and assume that f is not a function of t?

...Or do I approximate with something like $$\sum_ie^{2\sigma B_{i}}(t_{i+1}-t_i)$$

Having a tough time finding any detail in the literature here - any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If we have
$$S_t = S_0 e^{\sigma B_t},$$

then Itô expanding it gives
\begin{align}
dS &= \frac{\partial S}{\partial t} dt + \frac{\partial S}{\partial B} dB + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial B^2} (dB)^2 \\
&= 0 \cdot dt + \sigma S_0 e^{\sigma B}dB + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 S_0 e^{\sigma B} dt \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 S_t dt + \sigma S_tdB,
\end{align}
where we used that $(dB)^2=dt$.

Hence, we have that
\begin{align}
d\langle S \rangle_t := (dS_t)^2 = \sigma^2S_t^2dt,
\end{align}
so that the quadratic variation is given by
$$\langle S \rangle_t = \sigma^2 \int_0^t S_u^2 du.$$

Comment: @Pontius: I followed most of it except for the "Hence, we have that" part. Could you explain that ? Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds: Since dS=0.5*v^2*S*dt + v*S*dB, we have that (dS)^2 = ...dt^2 + ...dt*dB + ...dB^2 = ...dB^2 = ...dt, since dt^2~0, dt*dB~0, and dB^2 = dt. Quadratic variation is then given by integrating (dS^2)

Comment: Thanks Pontus. I get it now.  It's appreciated.